# How to decompress zip with password in windows 8 metro program?

Tags: c#, windows-8, .net-4.5

I have a zip password file and know this password.

I need open this zip file in  Windows 8 metro app program code.

But 'System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive' is not supported decompress zip with password in Windows 8 metro app program code.

I'm try SharpZipLib and DotNetZip.  BUT they are not support  net 4.5.  So i doesn't use them in my metro program code.

I'm try Ionic.Zip. It's ok in program code. I want to build packages to upload to the windows store.   But not pass in microsoft code review.

Is there another way?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly is not available for Windows Store apps, so you cannot use the `ExtractToDirectory` extension method of the [ZipFileExtensions class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.aspx).

Instead of DirectoryInfo, FileInfo, etc. use StorageFile. See [Accessing data and files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464959.aspx) and the [File access sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231445) for more information on how to read and write files in Metro style apps. Then you'll need to read the data from the file into a stream and then pass that to methods of one of the following class (your choice):

- [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) (which internally uses zlib as of .NET 4.5)
- [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) classes. Those are [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle1) to Metro style apps, even if the file specific extension methods are not.
- Windows Runtime type [Decompressor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.compression.decompressor.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) to decompress files.

Answer (score 0):

you can using https://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/. 
it support open file zip have password

code bellow

//if file zip have a file pdf , a file xml

async void Read(StorageFile file)
        {

```
        MemoryStream memoryFilePDf = new MemoryStream();

        MemoryStream memoryFileXml = new MemoryStream();

        FilePdf = null;

        FileXml = null;


        using (var zipStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            using (MemoryStream zipMemoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)zipStream.Length))
            {
                await zipStream.CopyToAsync(zipMemoryStream);
                try
                {
                    using (var archive = ZipArchive.Open(zipMemoryStream, PassWord))
                    {
                        bool isFilePdf = false;
                        foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                        {
                            if (!entry.Key.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf") && !entry.Key.ToLower().EndsWith(".xml"))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (entry.Key.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf"))
                            {
                                isFilePdf = true;
                                entry.WriteTo(memoryFilePDf);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isFilePdf = false;
                                entry.WriteTo(memoryFileXml);
                            }

                            var fileName = entry.Key.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).LastOrDefault();
                            var createFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await createFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                            {
                                // Write compressed data from memory to file
                                using (Stream outstream = stream.AsStreamForWrite())
                                {
                                    byte[] buffer = isFilePdf ? memoryFilePDf.ToArray() : memoryFileXml.ToArray();
                                    outstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    outstream.Flush();
                                }
                            }

                            if (isFilePdf)
                            {
                                FilePdf = createFile;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FileXml = createFile;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```